# Swap two rows in python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given `m` and `n`, swap the mth and nth rows of the 2-D NumPy array given below.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[4, 3, 1],
              [5, 7, 0],
              [9, 9, 3],
              [8, 2, 4]])
```

Example:

Input 1:

```
0
2
```

Output 1:

```
array([[9, 9, 3],
       [5, 7, 0],
       [4, 3, 1],
       [8, 2, 4]])
```

Comment: Your example is of a nested list, not a numpy array.

Answer (score 3):

You could use NumPy [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
a[(m, n), :] = a[(n, m), :]
```